# Why isnt the watson assistant conversation working for other users?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I've currently installed Watson Assistant chatbot for one of my clients new websites that was created with Wordpress. When I view the website the chatbot preforms correctly with an introductory message and is able to respond to questions. When he views the website the chatbot is there but does not display the introduction message and doesn't respond to any messages. The website is [chrisduffey.ai](https://chrisduffey.ai)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser dev tools, there's 401 unauthorized error

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_access","message":"Only authenticated users can access the REST API.","data":{"status":401}}
```

[Link](https://chrisduffey.ai/index.php?rest_route=/watsonconv/v1/message) to the error

There's an [IBM Watson Assistant WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/) available to use with your Wordpress.org website and here are the [step-by-step instructions](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-your-watson-assistant-chatbot-with-wordpress/) to set up the plugin with your credentials